How to list layers on the active elevation profile panel with PyQGIS
I begin with pyqgis and I try to list layers from a QGIS elevation profile widget ('bdtopo_v3batiment_z' in the picture). I found this class in the documentation but it returns None. How can I access to the active profile properties?
a = QgsElevationProfileCanvas()
b = a.layers()
print(b)
[]

Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site. The most common comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" If you don't include code in a coding Question, it is likely to be closed. Please [Edit] the Question to state what software release you are using, what you are attempting to accomplish, what you have tried, and where you are stuck.
